# avi recording index failure

Tags: indexing, directshow, avi

Since 3-4 Weeks I have Problems with Video-File Recording. Everytime I become an Index Fail after close / finish the Recorded File. But the Index is very important for me, because the recorded files should be used later for some Cut Processes. With this Index Failure it Cut me the wrong Part from the Video...

The Constalation is the Follow:

Logitech (B910HD) Webcam as Input Source => Xvid Codec as De/Encoder => Filewriter. All this done by a little, own developed Tool with the help of DirectShow (DirectShowLib-2005.dll).

I tried all logical debugging Steps... I has reinstalled Codecs / tried very lot of Codec Settings / tried other Computers and other Codecs (x264vfw) / reinstalled System (Windows 7 Pro x64 AND Windows XP Pro SP3) / changed WebCam (other B910HD and C920HD Pro) / ....

The more or less crazy thing is that its working very well before the 4 Weeks AND that is working fine on some other machines (same OS / exactly same Units and Hardware). So I though maybe its a Hardware failure from this Units (maybe HDD or Memory) but Tests of this Hardware was good too!

Comment:
Only VLC Media Player says the Index is defect. Windows Media Player tell me nothing and play the File....

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the B910 and also C920 webcams are not providing a constant framerate under all conditions. This leads to an incorrect video index. For me it helped to disable the auto-exposure feature.